# NullPointerException when long press on TextView with SpannableString

Tags: java, android, textview, spannablestring

I have a TextView with SpannableString because I want the do differnet thing when user click different position of the view. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    String str = "ClickMe";
    SpannableString spStr = new SpannableString(str);
    ClickableSpan clickSpan = new CustomizedClickableSpan(str);
    spStr.setSpan(clickSpan, 0, str.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tv.setText("PlainTextA");
    tv.append(spStr);
    tv.append("PlainTextB");
    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    setContentView(tv);
}

private class CustomizedClickableSpan extends ClickableSpan {
    String text;

    public CustomizedClickableSpan(String text) {
        super();
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        Toast.makeText(SpanTextView.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

After that, the textView's text is "PlainTextAClickMePlainTextB". And when I click the "ClickMe", the toast is showing. (It's just very well.)

But, when I long press the "ClickMe", the app crashed!
Here is my log:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.Editor.touchPositionIsInSelection(Editor.java:750)
at android.widget.Editor.performLongClick(Editor.java:851)
at android.widget.TextView.performLongClick(TextView.java:8390)
at android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run(View.java:18419)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:806)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:622)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**:
Thanks for @Blackbelt . I just add these code:

```
tv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //just consume the event
        return true;
    }
});
```

And the problem is solved!
BTW, what's the reason of the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: is it disabling the *Long Press* gesture a possibility for you?

Comment: @Blackbelt i guess not: *I want to do differnet thing when user click*

Comment: I got the same issue.I could fix this by setting font of the view(Editext/Textview) programmatically instead of XML.Please note that for me it was only happening on lollipop versions of Samsung reported by crashlytics.

Comment: I Suggest this. May be helpful.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58069628/3659492

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add a method to catch the `longClick` event. In this case, if you want to control the `TextView` :

```
tv.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        Toast.makeText(HomeSafeActivity.this, "Long preess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. And, the super class ClickableSpan doesn't has method onLongClick.

Comment: i know, that's why it was not annotated with `@Override`, check my update

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. Actually I don't need the long click event, I just want to avoid the crash.

Comment: @hanswim I've seen in your profile you havn't accepted any answer yet. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider upvoting or [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and **gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself**. Of course there is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76981/discussion-between-hanswim-and-jordi-castilla).

Comment: I got the same issue.I could fix this by setting font of the view(Editext/Textview) programmatically instead of XML.Please note that for me it was only happening on lollipop versions of Samsung reported by crashlytics.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with `setOnLongClickListener` has one side effect: `LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent` would not get `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`. 
For avoiding this problem you can call `TextView.setLongClickable(false)` instead.
It is important to call `setLongClickable` after `setMovementMethod`, because `setMovementMethod` calls `setLongClickable(true)` inside.

Comment: This should be a comment on the answer you are referring to.

Comment: I got the same issue.I could fix this by setting font of the view(Editext/Textview) programmatically instead of XML.Please note that for me it was only happening on lollipop versions of Samsung reported by crashlytics.